# Display only certain labels with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The X axis of this graph represents time in milliseconds.
I basically need to display only one 5 labels, one each second (1,2,3,4 and 5), however the graph contains too many elements and not every label is shown.
I tried looking on the Chart.js documentation but haven't found anything useful to my case.
Do you guys have any ideas on how can I do it?
Im gonna post my code below:

```
<head>
      <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function () {

    function generateLabels() {
        var chartLabels = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 5000; x++) {
            if(x%1000 == 0)
              chartLabels.push(x/1000);
            else
              chartLabels.push('');

        }
        return chartLabels;
    }

    function generateData() {
        var chartData = [];
        for (x = 0; x < 5000; x++) {
            chartData.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
        }
        return chartData;
    }

    function addData(numData, chart) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numData; i++) {
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(Math.random() * 100);
            chart.data.labels.push("Label" + i);
            var newwidth = $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(); // + 60
            $('.chartAreaWrapper2').width(newwidth);
        }
    }

    var chartData = {
        labels: generateLabels(),
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test Data Set",
            lineTension: 0,
            fill:false,
            pointBackgroundColor: "green", //Point Color
            pointBorderColor: "green",
            borderColor: "green", //Line Color
            pointStyle: "point",
            data: generateData()
        }]
    };



    $(function () {
        var rectangleSet = false;

        var canvasTest = $('#chart-Test');
        var chartTest = new Chart(canvasTest, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartData,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: true,
            options: {
              elements:{
                point:{
                  radius:1
                }
              },
                tooltips: {
                    titleFontSize: 0,
                    titleMarginBottom: 0,
                    bodyFontSize: 12
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 12,
                            display: true
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontSize: 12,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
        addData(5, chartTest);
    });
});

      </script> 
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
      <canvas id="chart-Test" height="300" width="5000"></canvas>
  </div>
  <canvas id="axis-Test" height="300" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correct, you want to show only 5 labels in your x-axis (1, 2, 3 ,4, second). Try this one:

```
var options =  {  
         scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                afterTickToLabelConversion: function(data){


                    var xLabels = data.ticks;

                    xLabels.forEach(function (labels, i) {
                        if (i % 1000 != 0){
                            xLabels[i] = '';
                        }
                    });
                } 
            }]   
        }
}
```

Comment: The fact is that there are a lot of elements in my graph and not every label is shown (I think its like one every 14/18 values) so if the labels of 1,2,3,4 and 5 seconds are not shown in the graph there is no way for me to display them.